# How to make web server software from scratch

Tags: webserver

I'm trying to make web server software (like httpd), but with less functions. I don't know how to start, but I know how to code in C, PHP, Python. How do I make web server software using those programming languages?

Comment: [Python includes one already](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python already has that platform. use these link it might be helpful
https://www.afternerd.com/blog/python-http-server/